# Complex, renamed Has Many Through relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a Wiki-style application. The basic models right now are User and Wiki. A User `has_many` Wikis she creates, and a Wiki `belongs_to` a User. So far so easy. Now the complications.

I want a Wiki to have as unlimited collaborating users. This makes a distinction between a Wiki's **owner** and **collaborators**, though both are Users. I figured this would be a good case for a Has Many Through relationship, so I created a join table: Collaboration.

Here are my migration generators (which I didn't deviate from). First Wiki:

```
rails g model Wiki body:text title:string owner_id:integer
```

Then User:

```
rails g model User name:string
```

Then Collaboration:

```
rails g model Collaboration wiki_id:integer collaborator_id:integer
```

The idea is that I should be able to call `wiki.owner` and `wiki.collaborators`, as well as `user.owned_wikis` and `user.collaborated_wikis`. I've gotten most of the way there by hardcoding my own methods. That is, this pretty much works:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def owned_wikis
    Wiki.where(owner_id: id)
  end

  def collaborations
    Collaboration.where(collaborator_id: id)
  end

  def collaborated_wikis
    collaborations.wikis
  end
end

class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.collaborators
    User.where(id: pluck(:collaborator_id))
  end

  def self.wikis
    Wiki.where(id: pluck(:wiki_id))
  end

  def wiki
    Wiki.where(id: wiki_id)
  end

  def collaborator
    User.where(id: collaborator_id)
  end
end

class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  def owner
    User.where(id: owner_id)
  end

  def collaborations
    Collaboration.where(wiki_id: id)
  end

  def collaborators
    collaborations.collaborators
  end
end
```

I could leave it at that, but this makes certain things (say, `wiki.collaborators << User.create(name: 'Whatever')` difficult/impossible. I'd love to do this all with AR relationships, but I'm having trouble. Here's where I am:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_wikis, class_name: 'Wiki', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :collaborations, foreign_key: 'collaborator_id'
  has_many :collaborated_wikis, class_name: 'Wiki', through: :collaborations
end

class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wiki
  belongs_to :collaborator, class_name: 'User'

  # The issue here is that relations of Collaborations don't respond to `collaborators` or `wikis`
end

class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :collaborators, class_name: 'User', through: :collaborations
end
```

And it's doing some of the basic stuff `user.owned_wikis`, `wiki.owner`, `w.collaborations`, etc, but **not** `w.collaborators` or `u.collaborated_wikis`.

For those two, I get these errors. `w.collaborators`:

```
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "collaborations" ON "users"."id" = "collaborations"."collaborator_id" WHERE "collaborations"."wiki_id" = $1  [["wiki_id", 1]]
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...sers" INNER JOIN "collaborations" ON "users"."id" = "collabo...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "collaborations" ON "users"."id" = "collaborations"."collaborator_id" WHERE "collaborations"."wiki_id" = $1
```

and `u.collaborated_wikis`:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :collaborated_wiki or :collaborated_wikis in model Collaboration. Try 'has_many :collaborated_wikis, :through => :collaborations, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :wiki or :collaborator?
```

Any ideas how to do this better? I would like a fully-fledged has-many-through relationship, so that I can do `wiki.collaborators << user` or `user.collaborated_wikis << wiki`. Of the sort described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), but with all these weird renaming kinks.

Any ideas how to string this up?

**SOLVED** - the final version resulting from the answer below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_wikis, class_name: 'Wiki', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :collaborations, foreign_key: 'collaborator_id'
  has_many :collaborated_wikis, through: :collaborations, source: :wiki
end

class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :wiki
  belongs_to :collaborator, class_name: 'User'
end

class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :collaborators, through: :collaborations, source: :collaborator
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the :source option

```
has_many :collaborated_wikis, through: :collaborations, source: :wiki

has_many :collaborators, through: :collaborations, source: :colaborator
```

However i would just change the colaborator_id to user_id on the Collaboration model, since you already have a "Collaborate" namespace on this model itself, which will allow you to stick more with rails defaults.

Comment: Awesome. This totally solved it. For those interested, I'll put my the final version suggested by this answer above. I might end up taking the `collaborator_id` => `user_id` suggestion, but it's good to know how to do it if I complicate things for myself with weirdly named foreign keys.